# How to start/run a .mount file (systemd)

Tags: mount, systemd

I have a pretty simple systemd unit file, but it doesn't end with .service, it ends with .mount. I'm not sure how exactly this makes it different, but when I start it using `systemctl start hello.mount`

I get this error `Where= setting doesn't match unit name` and well yes `Where=` is my mount point, so it points to a directory and not to a unit file.

So am I missing something? Do I have to start .mount unit files in a different way?

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount file to path
[Mount]
What=path to file....
Where=path to dir....
Type=btrfs
```

Comment: Uhm.. okay. May `whatever` contain dashes or would that cause problems?

Comment: Run `systemd-escape` to convert the "where". Eg `systemd-escape a-b` gives `a\x2db`

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the unit filename.
Man systemd.mount(5) in [Mount] section explains:

```
 Where=
           Takes an absolute path of a directory of the mount point. If the
           mount point does not exist at the time of mounting, it is
           created. This string must be reflected in the unit filename. (See
           above.) This option is mandatory.
```

So if in your Where you have a mount point directory called /mnt/disk-0 you should call your unit file mnt-disk-0.mount not hello.mount .

You can read more in [Man systemd.mount(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.mount.5.html).